# merge back to back rows based on start & end date

Tags: t-sql

I have a table as below, each row has `status`, `from` and `to` ordered by `Zone`. Where `To`  of a current row always matches `From` of next row in that zone.

```
Zone  Status   From        To  
z1    Open     2015-01-01  2015-01-05 
z1    Open     2015-01-05  2015-01-10
z1    Closed   2015-01-10  2015-01-15 
z1    Closed   2015-01-15  2015-01-20
z1    Open     2015-01-20  2015-01-25
z1    Open     2015-01-25  2015-01-26

z2    Closed   2015-01-01  2015-01-05
z2    Closed   2015-01-05  2015-01-10
z2    Closed   2015-01-10  2015-01-15
z2    Closed   2015-01-15  2015-01-18
z2    Open     2015-01-18  2015-01-19
z2    Open     2015-01-19  2015-01-20
z2    Closed   2015-01-20  2015-01-20
```

I want to convert above into below table

```
Zone  Status   From        To  
z1    Open     2015-01-01  2015-01-10
z1    Closed   2015-01-10  2015-01-20
z1    Open     2015-01-20  2015-01-26

z2    Closed   2015-01-01  2015-01-18
z2    Open     2015-01-18  2015-01-20
z2    Closed   2015-01-20  2015-01-20
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `lag` and friends https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Is there any identity or unique id column?

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH x AS
(
SELECT
    Zone,
    Status,
    CASE WHEN 
             COALESCE(LAG(Status) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY Zone ORDER BY Zone, [From]), '') <> Status
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LS,
    [From],
    [To]
FROM
    t
), Y AS
(
SELECT
    Zone,
    Status,
    SUM(LS) OVER (PARTITION BY Zone ORDER BY Zone, [From]) Grp,
    [From],
    [To]
FROM
    x
)
SELECT
    Zone,
    Status,
    MIN([From]) [From],
    MAX([To]) [To]
FROM
    y
GROUP BY
   Zone, Status, Grp
ORDER BY 
   Grp;
```

> ```
> Zone | Status | From                | To                 
> :--- | :----- | :------------------ | :------------------
> z1   | Open   | 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 10/01/2015 00:00:00
> z1   | Closed | 10/01/2015 00:00:00 | 20/01/2015 00:00:00
> z1   | Open   | 20/01/2015 00:00:00 | 26/01/2015 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=20f2bd953a96cbd9196f2611e5066d39)*